# Nginx custom configuration not applying during first deployment of Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have 2 custom nginx conf files. These configurations are not being applied during the initial Elastic Beanstalk environment creation.

They are being applied once I restart the app server from EB console.

Is this the expected behaviour ?

The files are,

```
# File path -> .platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/00_application.conf
# This file overrides the default EB generated conf file to add 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header

location / {
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;

    proxy_set_header    Connection          $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
}
```

and

```
# File path -> .platform/nginx/conf.d/https.conf
# HTTPS server - enables SSL configuration

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
    include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: Which programming language are you using? You can place an nginx.conf file in the .ebextensions/nginx folder to override the Nginx configuration but only for Java or Go. That would solve the issue.

Comment: @Bob I am using Python 3.8 on Amazon Linux 2 platform. I don't think it is limited to only Java and Go because it works when I restart the server and for any other subsequent deployments.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I meant there is a workaround from Java and Go.

Comment: @Bob Ah! Got it. But as I understand that will be deprecated in future for Amazon Linux 2